# Dynamically generate properties in oobjects and function to loop through it?

Tags: node.js, fs

I am coding a httpfileserver. It doesn't use a database but rather save the files on the hard-drive just like any other file.

To make it more efficient it responds with a JavaScript object containing all files and directorys in the hierarchy the files are in. That is the idea at least. I am unable to make a function which does this since I cannot find a way to make the dynamically generated "paths" in the object go "deep" enough.

The function current function I've got works by taking the directory a step down in the object. However, this only works a step down. It fails when it is multiple steps down and thus can't handle more complex directory hierarchies.

I am using fs to read directorys and files.

Example of expected output of a working function:

```
jsobject = {file0: {
    filename : "sample.txt",
    content  : "this is sample.txt"
    },
    directory0 : {
        dirname : "directory",
        content : {
            file0 : {
                filename: "sample2.txt",
                content : "this is sample2.txt"
            },
            directory0 : {
                dirname : "directory2,",
                content : {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The function:

```
function readdir(dirtoread, subto) {

    if (dirtoread === undefined) {
        var dirtoread = fs.readdirSync("./Files", {encoding: "utf8"})[_.size(fs.readdirSync("./Files", {encoding: "utf8"})) - 1];
    }
        var fncounter = 0;
        var dircounter = 0;

        var files = fs.readdirSync("./Files/" + dirtoread,{encoding:"utf8"});
            for(var i = 0; i < _.size(files); i++) {

                if(files[i].toString().indexOf(".") !== -1) {



                    var nfile = "file" + fncounter;
                    var fname = files[i];

                    if(subto != undefined) {

                        var fcontent = fs.readFileSync("Files/" + dirtoread + "/" + files[i], {encoding:"utf8"});

                        json[subto].content[nfile] = {filename : fname, 
                            content: fcontent
                         };      


                    } else {
                        var fcontent = fs.readFileSync("Files/" + dirtoread + "/" + files[i], {encoding:"utf8"});
                        json[nfile] = {filename : fname, 
                            content: fcontent
                         };                        
                    }


                    fncounter++;

                } else {

                    var ndir = "directory" + dircounter;
                    var dname = files[i];
                    var nextdir = "/" + dirtoread + "/" + dname;

                    if (subto != undefined) {

                        json[subto].content[ndir] = {dirname : dname,
                                      content: {}
                                    }
                                    readdir(nextdir, ndir);
                    }else {

                    json[ndir] = {dirname : dname,
                                  content: {}
                                }

                                readdir(nextdir, ndir);
                            }


                    dircounter++;
                }
            }
            dirtoread = "not set";

}
```

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: Sure. What code do you want? The function that kind of doesn't work?

Comment: yes the function that seems not to work..

Comment: You might just want to use a package to do the filesystem walk: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-walk

Comment: You need to create an recursive function (a function that calls itself) and start building the json object - do a web search about recursive js function. or try maybe fs-walk has something similar to offer @MoltasDev

Comment: @DevFlamur This function calls itself but it isn't enough since it can't handle deeper levels of the dir hierarchy.

Comment: Although fs-walk simplified the code a lot, I am still unable to properly rebuild the dir hierarchy in the object. Is there an easy way to do this too?